# Minimum value of an expression

Tags: optimization

What would be the minimum value of 
$$ 
(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)(1+d)
\left({\frac{1}{a}}+{\frac{1}{b}}+{\frac{1}{c}}+{\frac{1}{d}}\right)
$$ 
Given that $a,b,c,d$ are all positive real non zero number

**THE ANSWER IS ${\frac{4^5}{27}}$**

Comment: Do you know multivariate calculus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Symmetry an optimal value will be attained when $a=b=c=d$ so it suffice to consider
\begin{eqnarray*}
S=(1+a)^4\frac{4}{a}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Differentiation gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{dS}{da}=\frac{-4(1+a)^4}{a^2}+\frac{16(1+a)^3}{a}=\frac{4(1+a)^3(3a-1)}{a^2}
\end{eqnarray*}
Setting $\frac{dS}{da}=0$ gives $a=\frac{1}{3}$ and the minimum value is $\color{red}{\frac{4^5}{27}}$. (as stated in the question).

EDIT ...
In order to show that an optimal value is attained when $a=b=c=d$. Calculate the partial derivatives
\begin{eqnarray*}
S&=&(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)(1+d)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}\right)\\
\frac{\partial S}{\partial a}&=&(1+b)(1+c)(1+d)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}\right)+(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)(1+d)\frac{-1}{a^2}
\end{eqnarray*}
So we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1+a}{a^2}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}=\frac{1+b}{b^2}=\frac{1+c}{c^2}=\frac{1+d}{d^2}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now note that the function $f(x)=\frac{1+x}{x^2}$ is monotonic ... $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$ so $\color{blue}{a=b=c=d}$.

Comment: Could you please tell me what was it that made you consider this to be symmetric and also that it could be used to find the minimum. Basically the train of thought before realizing symmetry is there and it is the key.

Comment: @SaakshyaDevat I have added an edit to my answer to justify the claim that the minimum is attained (in this example) when the values are equal.

Answer (score 6):

With symmetry, you expect $a=b=c=d$.  So minimizing $f(a)=(1+a)^4(4/a)$ is quite straightforward.

Comment: No. If you take $a=b=c=d$ you get $(1+a)^4$$(\frac{4}{a})$

Comment: No statement of the value of $a$ at which the maximum is attained ... no statement of what the maximum value is ... seriously ?

Comment: I didn't understand this solution.

Comment: @SaakshyaDevat, thanks, corrected.

Comment: @paul could you please explain to me again why there is symmetry and why we considered it.